# I want to change the data frame structure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

My current data frame look like:

```
CREATED_DATE    STATE
02/03/15 0:00   Texas
02/03/15 0:00   Texas
02/03/17 16:19  Texas
02/03/15 16:19  Florida
02/03/16 16:19  Florida
02/03/16 16:19  Florida
02/03/15 16:19  Alabama
02/03/16 16:19  Alabama
02/03/15 16:19  North Carolina
02/03/15 16:19  North Carolina
02/03/16 16:19  North Carolina
```

I want to change it into:

```
STATE   2015    2016    2017
Texas   2   0   1
Florida 1   2   0
Alabama 1   1   0
North Carolina  2   1   0
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['STATE', df.CREATED_DATE.dt.year]).size().unstack(1, fill_value=0)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) here:

```
pd.crosstab(df['STATE'], df['CREATED_DATE'].dt.year)
```

[out]

```
CREATED_DATE    2015  2016  2017
STATE                           
Alabama            1     1     0
Florida            1     2     0
North Carolina     2     1     0
Texas              2     0     1
```